# Как вывести на экран элементы массива в обратном порядке в Java?

Tags: java

Имеется массив из 10 строк. Моя задача вывести на экран элементы массива в обратном порядке и каждый с новой строчки.

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String[] love = new String[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < love.length; i++){
            System.out.println(love[i]); // вывожу элементы массива с начала

            ?????????????????     // вывод элементов массива в обратном порядке

        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```java
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String[] love = new String[10];

        for (int i = love.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            System.out.println(love[i]);
        }
    }
}
```